# Best way to get midnight on a specific day in a specific time zone in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, datetime, timezone

I'm working with a Rails app that gets fed a date as a String in format "YYYY-MM-DD" and I am wondering what the best way to convert it to a TimeWithZone object set to midnight in a specific time zone, which is provided by a database also in the form of a String.

Essentially I want this:

> "2016-06-01", "America/New_York" => Wed, 01 Jun 2016 00:00:00 EDT -04:00
>
> "2016-06-01", "Europe/Berlin" => Wed, 01 Jun 2016 00:00:00 CEST +02:00
>
> "2016-01-01", "America/New_York" => Fri, 01 Jan 2016 00:00:00 EST -05:00
>
> "2016-01-01", "Europe/Berlin" => Fri, 01 Jan 2016 00:00:00 CET +01:00

Now I know it is definitely ***not*** simply Date.parse(x).to_datetime.in_time_zone(y).beginning_of_day since for the "America/New_York" examples, that would yield "Tue, 31 May 2016 00:00:00 EDT -04:00" and "Thu, 31 Dec 2015 00:00:00 EST -05:00" respectively, so I've thought about correcting that by adding a day if utc_offset is negative, so the method I've built basically looks like this:

```
def midnight_in_time_zone(date_string, time_zone_string)
  time_with_zone = Date.parse(date_string).
    to_datetime.
    in_time_zone(time_zone_string).
    beginning_of_day
  
  time_with_zone += 1.day if time_with_zone.utc_offset < 0
  
  time_with_zone
end
```

This works the way that I want, but it feels like I'm reinventing the wheel in a hacky way since what I am trying to do seems like such a basic function, so I'm wondering if there are builtin methods I don't know about that I could use to make this simpler or if anyone knows of a better way of doing this.

Comment: Ideally you'd be working with `DateTime` objects initially, which would then mean you could get the end result easier. I've had to craft similar code in the past and am not aware of an easier way.

Comment: @Tass Is there a way to create a new DateTime object with a time zone offset using the standard name like "America/New_York"?  I know that the offset number as a String like "-5" could be used, but since that changes with Daylight Saving Time for most time zones in North America and Europe, I can't think of a good way of managing that without it feeling even more like reinventing the wheel, so using the standard name and letting Rails determine the offset would be ideal.

Comment: And speaking of Daylight Savings, I just realized that my "1 day" correction won't work if it falls on a day of a Daylight Savings change in time zones behind UTC as the result would be either 11 PM or 1 AM depending on the direction of the change.

Comment: I believe you're looking to use something like the `TZInfo` gem. In our application it's installed as a dependency for at least a couple other gems. You can check out the example usage: https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo#example-usage

Comment: (I'm scouring through some custom one-off scripts I've made at work to see if I can provide an example for you.)

Comment: @Tass Okay, so you're suggesting something like this?

`def midnight_in_time_zone(date_string, time_zone_string);
  tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get(time_zone_string);
  tz.local_to_utc(Time.parse(date_string)).to_datetime;
end`

Comment: That looks about right, yes. The example we used required a hard-coded time, but here it is: `Time.new(year, month, day, 8, 00, 00).in_time_zone("America/Chicago")`. Looks like you have a handle on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def midnight_in_time_zone(date_string, time_zone_string)
   date_string.in_time_zone(time_zone_string)
end
```

this line increases 1 day automatically if time_with_zone.utc_offset's value smaller than 0

Example result:

```
#Your code puts
time_with_zone = Date.parse("2016-01-01").to_datetime.in_time_zone("America/New_York").beginning_of_day
#=> Thu, 31 Dec 2015 00:00:00 EST -05:00
#If you try this
date_string.in_time_zone(time_zone_string)
#=> Fri, 01 Jan 2016 00:00:00 EST -05:00
```

Comment: Thx, but it should be noted that your solution works in Rails 4.  Some of our servers are still running on Rails 3, but I think I can massage it until they get upgraded.